# NodeJS make problems under ELB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

we are using  ELB to Load balance between two NODEJS server.

Suddenly yesterday the service has started to recieve errors while i have two servers under the ELB.

when removing one of the servers and staying with only one server the service is working fine.

i don't have any log of traffic direction between the the servers and it seems that the system works fine with one server (no matter which one of them) and doesn't work with more than one server.

Any suggestions what should we check ?

10x!

Comment: What doesn't doesn't work mean exactly? First thing to check is whether the servers are receiving requests. They may be receiving but it can happen that due to some queues or connection pool limitations the requests get queued up and no response can be sent back to the client.

Comment: its like we trying to "talk" with nodejs but with no success ,my application just freeze till i remove one of the elb instance.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with your ELB configurations. Otherwise, the Node app doesn't have any reason not to serve the requests considering it's completely isolated from the other Node processes on a different server.